# Server-side access control using client's X509 certificate DN

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, grizzly

Peoples,

I using JAX-RS with Jersey 2.17 and Grizzly as my HTTP server.  I have client authentication configured and working, however, I am attempting to implement access control on the client's X.509 certificate DN.  This will give me equivalent capabilities to what I have with Apache httpd and FakeBasicAuth configured.

I have attempted to use a ContainerRequestFilter but can seem to find a way to get a reference to the client's DN associated with the TLS session.  Can someone show me a way to get access to the certificate with the ContainerRequestFilter or any other mechanism for achieving the same end goal?

EDIT:  I tried the "@javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpServletRequest req;" last night before posting but the HttpServletRequest context was always null.  I am using the GrizzlyHttpServerFactory as follows:

```
GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                getServerURI(), getResourceConfig(), true,
                new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContext.get())
                    .setNeedClientAuth(true).setClientMode(false))
```

Which is believe is not a servlet container, and therefore, does not support the HttpServletRequest context.  I quickly looked at the GrizzlyWebContainerFactory but initialization is completely different and would like to avoid going though that pain.  Is there any other way to get access to the user certificate in a "javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter"?

Thank you!

John

Comment: See the Servlet Specification. The client certificate is available via a request property.

Answer (score 3):

From the Java Servlet specification:

> If there is an SSL certificate associated with the request, it must be exposed by the servlet container to the servlet programmer as an array of objects of type `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` and accessible via a
>   `ServletRequest` attribute of `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`.
>
> The order of this array is defined as being in ascending order of trust. The first
>   certificate in the chain is the one set by
>   the client, the next
>   is the one used to
>   authenticate the first, and so on.

In practical terms, this means doing:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])
    req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")
if (certs != null && certs.length > 0) {
    X509Certificate cert = certs[0];  // the client certificate
    // further processing (extract and compare DN, etc)
}
```

If you don't already have access to the `ServletRequest`, you can use `@Context` to bring it into scope in your service class:

```
@javax.ws.rs.core.Context
HttpServletRequest req;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried this last night before posting but the HttpServletRequest context was always null, but now that you specifically identified this as the solution I did some additional digging.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the Jersey mailing list I was able to work out the answer.  Here is the woking RequestFilter example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @javax.inject.Inject
    private javax.inject.Provider<org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request> request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext filterContext) {
        if (request != null) {
            log.debug("User principle: " + request.get().getUserPrincipal().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!